# Поиск максимума с помощью goto

Tags: c, goto

Как найти минимум и максимум в массиве используя оператор goto.

Код:

```
i = 0;
newMaxOfArray:
    maxValue = array[i];
    i++;
newMinOfArray:
    minValue = array[i];
    i++;

if (array[i] > maxValue && i < 10){
    goto newMaxOfArray;}
else{
    i++;}

i = 0;
if (minValue > array[i] && i < 10){
    goto newMinOfArray;}
else {
    i++;}
```

Код работает некорректно. Иногда выдает не минимум и максимум, а другие числа. Я знаю, что goto не лучший вариант, но что я не так сделал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> newMaxOfArray:
>     maxValue = array[i];
>     i++;
> newMinOfArray:
>     minValue = array[i];
>     i++;
> ```

Каждый раз, когда ты делаешь

```
goto newMaxOfArray;
```

Присваиваются оба значения - максимум и минимум, после чего поиск продолжает искать максимум. После перехода на вторую метку, поиск тоже продолжает искать максимум. Если перенесёшь второй кусок после второго `i = 0`, то должно заработать.

Comment: Так тоже работать не будет, потому что нет переходов из веток else, т.е. поиск минимума как и максимума завершиться при первом же несоответствии.

Comment: @tilin, пожалуй да, что-то там будет не так...

Answer (score 0):

Работать будет вот так:

```
    int i = 0;
newMaxOfArray:
    maxValue = array[i];
newMaxOfArray1:
i++;

if (array[i] > maxValue && i < 10){
    goto newMaxOfArray;}
else if(i<10){
    goto newMaxOfArray1;}
else{
    i++;
}

i = 0;
newMinOfArray:
    minValue = array[i];
newMinOfArray1:
    i++;
if (minValue > array[i] && i < 10){
    goto newMinOfArray;}
else if(i<10){
    goto newMinOfArray1;
}
else{
    i++;
}
```

Comment: а зачем еще else if, если в первом условии и так есть проверка для i ?

Comment: по первому условию переход будет только если обновился максимум/минимум. А если нет то приск завершиться на этом индексе. И если далее в массиве есть более большие или маленькие значения, то до них не дойдет. Если так не сделать, то для массива {10,31,23,44,5,6,7,8,9,0} минимум будет определен как 10, а максимум как 31